# How to calculate Madelung's constant for NaCl?

Tags: atoms, intermolecular-forces, solid-state-chemistry

Madelung's constant for $\ce{NaCl}$ is $1.748$. 
What I tried to so is sum up all the individual interactions into $1$ component where the $X$s are the nucleus and the electron if it was a $2$ atom system. Is this the correct way to go about it? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. A screenshot or picture of an exercise is not searchable. Please consider rewriting it, so that it can be of help for future visitors.

Comment: As hinted at in the question, the series as you have written it out 6 - 12/rt(2) + 8/rt(3) - ... does not converge rapidly. I am not exactly sure how the value is obtained though.

Comment: Is this the correct way to add up the interactions though?

Answer (score 3):

The series $\displaystyle \frac{6}{1}-\frac{12}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{8}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{6}{2}+\frac{24}{\sqrt{5}}\pm\ldots$ diverges as has been proven in 1951.

The correct value can be obtained by summation over lattice cubes with edge length $2n+1$ and getting the limit for $n \to \infty$. This has been shown in 1985.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madelung_constant) provides more information and further reading on this.